# Angular js empty $routeparams

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm new on angular js and i'm trying to get parameters from the url i've read some documentation about routeparams but i'm getting it empty.
here is my code

```
  var study = angular.module('study', ['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

study.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('edit/:id', {
        controller: 'EditController'
   });
}]).controller('EditController',

function($scope, $http, $compile, $rootScope, $routeParams, $route ) {

    $scope.item = null;

    console.log($routeParams);
    console.log($rootScope);
    var id = $routeParams.$id;

    $scope.onLoad = $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'item',
            data: {id:id}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.item = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(status);
        });


});
```

Comment: what did `console.log($routeParams);` do?

Comment: You have not attached a template to the route either? Why?